# Why doesn't nio filesystem move work outside try block?

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to use nio's filesystem to rename files in a zip file.

The example below from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) works for me.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;


public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");
        Path javaPath = Paths.get("C:/test.zip");
        
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(javaPath, env)) {
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.txt");        
            Files.move( pathInZipfile,pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("/test_changed.txt"), 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 
        } 
    }
}
```

But when I remove the `try` block:

```java
        FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(javaPath, env);
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.txt");        
            Files.move( pathInZipfile,pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("/test_changed.txt"), 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
```

the code compiles but the file is not renamed.

Why is that?

Comment: Does it work if you add `zipfs.close()`? I bet it does. And the reason the first one works is that it's using try-with-resources which handles close automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What you tried

The first example you posted is using try-with-resources:

```
try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(javaPath, env)) {
    Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.txt");
    Files.move(pathInZipfile, pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("/test_changed.txt"),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

The [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) includes several examples and more explanation, but
the main thing you're encountering is this:

> *The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.*

In your first example, "zipfs" is being automatically closed at the end of the try block.

---

In your second example, you've removed the "try" altogether, so you're creating a resource (zipfs) without calling [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#close--). From the Javadoc:

> *Closing a file system will close all open channels, directory-streams, watch-service, and other closeable objects associated with this file system.*

Skipping the call to close() will leave those things open, which is what's happening in your second example.

```
FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(javaPath, env);
Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.txt");
Files.move(pathInZipfile, pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("/test_changed.txt"),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

#### Solution

To get your code working (safely) without try-with-resources, you could change your code to something like the following:

- declare "zipfs", assign to null
- create a new "try" block, doing whatever things you were doing previously
- create a new "finally" block that closes zipfs (if it isn't null)

```
FileSystem zipfs = null;
try {
    zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(javaPath, env);
    Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.txt");
    Files.move(pathInZipfile, pathInZipfile.resolveSibling("/test_changed.txt"),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} finally {
    if (zipfs != null) {
        zipfs.close();
    }
}
```

If you wanted to be unsafe, you could remove the try-finally and just tack on zipfs.close() at the end. But this is risky – if anything goes wrong in the lines before, close() would not be called.

Safest is to use some form of "try", and the simplest is to use try-with-resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What are the risks of not using try block? If things go wrong, are there consequences other than the intended changes do not occur?

Comment: You're welcome. For leaving resources open, it depends on the resource, but generally: things can go wrong and/or you can leak resources. You discovered one of the "things go wrong" scenarios: you want to update a file, but it doesn't update. An example of leaked resource could be: open a network connection, never close it, open other connections without closing them, too; over time this can consume all available network connections to the remote host/server and eventually that host would stop responding to new requests.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the kind explanations. If anything comes to mind, do you have any docs about NIO's filesystem that I can read up on? I don't have particular concerns in mind at the moment. But it would be nice to be aware of potential pitfalls that end up hurting the integrity of the data files I manipulate.

Comment: There's a lot of info in the [Java Core Libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/core/java-nio.html) documentation, and a small amount in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html). There are probably a few good books about NIO, too, though I don't have any specific recommendations.